# How to call a method in FORM class from another class but both are same namespace

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

```
class Form1 : Form 
{ 
  public void enable() 
  { 
  //1st method which i want to call from another class 
  } 
  public void display() 
  { 
  //2nd method which i want to call from another class 
  } 
} 
class Buffer : signal 
{ 
  protected override Analyse() 
  { 
  //from here i want to call two functions in form class 
  } 
}
```

this is how my code looks like anyone please reply this tread.........

Answer (score 1):

When creating the Buffer class, you have to pass reference to the real instance of Form1 then just use that instance. Sample code:

```
class Form1 : Form 
{ 
  public void InitBuffer()
  {
    Buffer b = new Buffer(this);
    ...
  }

  public void enable() 
  { 
  //1st method which i want to call from another class 
  } 
  public void display() 
  { 
  //2nd method which i want to call from another class 
  } 
} 
class Buffer : signal 
{ 
  private Form1 form;

  public Buffer(Form1 parent)
  {
    form = parent;
  }
  protected override Analyse() 
  { 
    form.enable();
    form.display();
  } 
}
```

You can't grab the true instance of Form1 just like that out of nowhere.