# Calling a function on the form from a class

Tags: c#, class

I'm struggeling with calling a method from a Toolkit-class.

I quite often have to build projects that use similar functions.
In order to make it easier for myself, I'm currently in the process of putting a lot of these functions in a class which I can easily use in all of the projects. One of the functions I am using is to add a statusstrip to my form.

I've managed to get the statusstrip on there from my form, but now I'm trying to update the toolstriplabels on my statusstrip from within my class and that's where I get stuck. I'm trying to call the toolstriplabel or even a method to update the labels on the form but it doesn't recognize the form.

Here is what I have:

```
namespace Bold
{

public class BoldTools
{
    private Form frmMain;

    public BoldTools(Form parent)
    {
        frmMain = parent;
    }

    public void test()
    {
        if (frmMain.lblThreadStatus.InvokeRequired)
        {
            frmMain.lblThreadStatus.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                frmMain.lblThreadStatus.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(R, G, B);
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            frmMain.lblThreadStatus.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(R, G, B);
        }

        frmMain.updateStatusLabel();
    }
}
}
namespace MyMainForm
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        // CREATE AN INSTANCE TO THE GENERIC FUNCTIONS
        public Bold.BoldTools tools;

        private void setupTools()
        {
            // LINK THE BOLD CLASS
            tools = new Bold.BoldTools(this);    


            // SET UP THE STATUSES
            tools.Test();
        }
    }
}
```

This code was based on another thread here at Stack OverFlow ([How to call a method in FORM class from another class but both are same namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312713/how-to-call-a-method-in-form-class-from-another-class-but-both-are-same-namespac)) but without any luck.
When I use frmMain it doesn't recognize the methods that are in the Main Form.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared the member `frmMain` in `BoldTools` as `Form`. So whenever you access it, the compiler only knows the methods of `Form` but not of `frmMain`.

Change the declaration to this:

```
public class BoldTools
{
    private frmMain _frmMain;

    public BoldTools(frmMain parent)
    {
        _frmMain = parent;
    }
```

Now the compiler knows that your member is of type `frmMain` and not only the base type `Form`.

I added an underscore to the member name `_frmMain` to distinguish it from the type name `frmMain`.

But note that `frmMain` as type name does not match C# naming conventions. You should consider a better name like `MainForm` or something like this.

Comment: This solved it for me. However I also had to add my NameSpace to the frmMain. I actually didn't know that this was an object in CSharp. Can I derive my namespace somewhere when I assign the form to make it more generic?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the type `Form` to store the form object in your class. The compiler will then only know about the methods that exist in that class, nothing more.

You will either have to tell the actual type to the class or add an interface containing the methods you want to call on the form.